# Trap Ctrl-C in awk script

Tags: shell-script, awk, trap

I believe <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> can be trapped in bash scripts. Is it also possible to trap it inside an Awk script in order to handle that event?

For example, for aborting processing, but printing the results of what has been processed already, instead of just silenty quitting?

Comment: you ll have to wrap it in a shell script or write an extension to awk AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, start by reading that: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Dynamic-Extensions.html#Dynamic-Extensions

Comment: An example: https://github.com/takubo/awk-posix-signal

Comment: If you want a portable solution that works with the various versions of `awk` that are out there - not possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not aware of any `awk` implementation that has support for that. You could [write an extension for `gawk` for that](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Dynamic-Extensions.html#Dynamic-Extensions), but here, I'd rather switch to another language.

`perl` makes it easy to convert `awk` scripts with its `a2p` script.

For instance, if you have an `awk` script like:

```
{count[$0]++}
END {
  for (i in count) printf "%5d %s\n", count[i], i
}
```

`a2p` on it will give you something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if $running_under_some_shell;
                        # this emulates #! processing on NIH machines.
                        # (remove #! line above if indigestible)

eval '$'.$1.'$2;' while $ARGV[0] =~ /^([A-Za-z_0-9]+=)(.*)/ && shift;
                        # process any FOO=bar switches

while (<>) {
    chomp;      # strip record separator
    $count{$_}++;
}

foreach $i (keys %count) {
    printf "%5d %s\n", $count{$i}, $i;
}
```

Which you can edit to add your signal handling (and remove that processing of `var=value` arguments which we don't want here, and the part intended for systems that don't support `#!`):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub report {
  foreach $i (keys %count) {
      printf "%5d %s\n", $count{$i}, $i;
  }
}

$SIG{INT} = sub {
  print STDERR "Interrupted\n";
  report;
  $SIG{INT} = 'DEFAULT';
  kill('INT', $$); # report dying of SIGINT.
};

while (<>) {
    chomp;      # strip record separator
    $count{$_}++;
}

report;
```

---

Another alternative could be to interrupt the *feeding of data* to `awk`, and have `awk` ignore the SIGINT, like instead of:

```
awk '{count[$0]++};END{for (i in count) printf "%5d %s\n", count[i], i}' file
```

do:

```
cat file | (
  trap '' INT
  awk '{count[$0]++};END{for (i in count) printf "%5d %s\n", count[i], i}'
)
```

<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> will then kill `cat` but not `awk`. `awk` will still keep on processing remaining input still in the pipe.

To detect the <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> in `awk`, you could do:

```
(cat file && echo cat terminated normally) | (
  trap '' INT
  awk '{count[$0]++}
       END{
         if ($0 == "cat terminated normally") delete count[$0]
         else print "Interrupted"
         for (i in count) printf "%5d %s\n", count[i], i}'
)
```

Comment: I adopted your final example and it works great! Thanks.

Comment: I do not have `a2p`script in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal using A shell (bash  or dash or whatever ) wrapper script that just forwards the inputs to the awk script in addition to handling the signal trapping.